# Automatically open Bandbox after open modal window

Tags: zk

In modal window I have Bandbox component which calls a command on "onOpen" event for showing next modal window to select some item for bandbox. I need to open this bandbox automatically after creating main modal window. So I do these steps:

1. Open main modal window by calling "doModal()"
2. Call global-command to set values in viewmodel of main modal window
3. In the same global-command call the method which is called by bandox on "onOpen" event to show next modal window.

Problem is that next modal is shown behind main modal. I need the next modal in front of main modal to access it.

Thanks for advices.

Comment: i'm not sure what you're doing there. can you please provide a minimal example in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe a command at client side. For more information, please refer to this [article](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2015/February/ZK8_Series:_UI_Template_Injection#More_Advanced_Usage)

For example,

```
wgt.$binder().after('commandName', callbackFuncation);
```